# Drawing a line between first and last QPoint on a QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap

I have a class that allows the user to draw a continuous line on an image by clicking anywhere on the image to create dots that automatically connect with each other.

```
GraphicsScene::GraphicsScene(QObject *parent) :
    QGraphicsScene(parent){

    //...
    qimOriginal = QImage((uchar*)src.data, src.cols, src.rows, src.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qimOriginal));
}

void GraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *mouseEvent){
    if (mouseEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton){

        QPoint pos = mouseEvent->scenePos().toPoint();
        pol.append(pos);
        if(pol.size() > 1){
            QPainterPath myPath;
            myPath.addPolygon(pol);
            addPath(myPath,QPen(Qt::red,1));
        }
    }
}
```

In my Dialog window that uses the `GraphicsScene` I have a button which on click returns the vector from `GraphicsScene` with the coordinates of the points. Before it returns the vector I want to draw a line between the first and last point of the `QPolygon` to create an area. Following is my `GraphicsScene::getCoordinates()` function:

```
std::vector<Point2f> GraphicsScene::getCoordinates(){
    qDebug() << pol.first() << pol.last();
    addLine(QLine(pol.first(),pol.last()),QPen(Qt::red,1));

    std::vector<Point2f> vecPoint;
    if (pol.size()>2){
        std::vector<QPoint> myVec = pol.toStdVector();

        for(int i=0; i<myVec.size(); i++) {
            QPoint point = myVec[i];
            Point2f p(point.x(), point.y());
            vecPoint.push_back(p);
        }

        pol.clear();
        this->clear();
        return vecPoint;
    }
    else{
         cout << "empty vector" << endl;
         return vecPoint;
    }

}
```

My problem is that for some reason `addLine(QLine(pol.first(),pol.last()),QPen(Qt::red,1));` does not draw anything on my image.

Comment: `addLine(QLine(pol.first(),pol.last()),QPen(Qt::red,1));` should work, code is normal, but when you call `this->clear();` then you delete all items in scene.

Comment: yes i'm aware this->clear(); clears the scene. I did have QThread::sleep(1); after the addLine() line but that didn't show the line. I want the user to see that their line connects, run the code to pass the vector and then clear the scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said:

```
 I did have QThread::sleep(1); after the addLine()
```

And believe me, it is source of your problem. `QThread::sleep(1);` sleeps, but it doesn't mean that your changes (your addLine) is showed on screen, no!

And this code, you know it from one of my answers doesn't add line at the moment, it waits 1 second and after this you can see this line. It is thread issue.

```
if(pol.size() > 1){
    QPainterPath myPath;
    myPath.addPolygon(pol);
    addPath(myPath,QPen(Qt::red,1));

    qDebug() << pol.first() << pol.last();
    addLine(QLine(pol.first(),pol.last()),QPen(Qt::red,1));
    Sleep(1000);//Sleep from WinApi
}
```

It source of your problem, but how to solve this? It is another question, but I can suggest you to try to use

```
QTimer::singleShot(1000,this,SLOT(echo()));
```

In slot you should clear your scene and of course you should remove

```
QThread::sleep(1);
```

from your code.